# sbt unresolved dependency for spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

build.sbt:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.1.1";

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided";

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVersion;
```

output:

```
[error] (myproject/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.2: not found
```

Any idea? I am new to sbt and spark. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2";` without **scala version**, see **maven repo**:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.spark%7Cspark-cassandra-connector_2.11%7C2.0.2%7Cjar

There are 2 solutions for this:

1. `"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.2"` explicitly set **Scala version**  for dependency
2. `"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2"`, use `%%` with **artifact id**, this way, the **SBT** will auto base on your project's **scala version** to expand to the **solution 1**.

Comment: thanks. i changed it to `libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVersion;
` now,  the error is ` Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-tags` any idea?

Comment: @BAE did you try the first method that Chegpohi advised?